# "Mobile User" Extract or report

Tags: user, mobile

I am looking to pull a report/extract that says which users have the following checkbox marked as true. I have tried getting this data in multiple ways, but can't seem to find the object this field is stored in. When looking at the User object it is not there, the closest I can find is userpermissionsmobileuser which is not the same as this field. If someone could advise me on what object this is hidden within, that would be helpful.

[image: Picture of the filed on the user detail page]

Comment: Why do you think `userpermissionsmobileuser` is not the same field? In fact it seems quite likely to have a label of `Mobile User` and control exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I see this has not been answered properly yet, and not sure if you still need it but it is the field UserPreferencesHides1BrowserUI on the User object.  Thing to note is that the boolean value is opposite to what you think.  If the value is True, then the check box is unchecked and vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

The API name for the Mobile User checkbox field on the Standard User object is indeed UserPermissionsMobileUser and that is the field that should be used for reporting on whether or not the user is a Mobile User